# Enable Version control checkbox in Repository service administration console?

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

May be very simple question for you guys. But I just want to clear my doubt.
I have seen option "Enable Version Control" while creating repository service. Can somebody tell me, what is the use of version control there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing tricky here - if you choose this option, the repository will support versioning for all the objects, e.g. reusable transformations, mappings, sessions, workflows. You will have to check out the objects to edit them and then check them in, you will be able to view object's history, compare the revisions, revert changes, etc.